# grails select box Cannot cast String to List

Tags: grails

I have the following in a select box

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="machinename">Portails</label>
<select name='portalsChoice' multiple class="form-control">
    <g:each in="${portals}" var="portal">
        <option>${portal.name}</option>
    </g:each>
</select>
</div>
```

Then, in a controller, I get all parameter like this :

```
def mymethod() {
List<String> portalsChoice = params.portalsChoice
...
}
```

If I select 2 elements, it works well.
I I select only 1 element, I have the following error : **Cannot cast object 'my string' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'**

What is the best way to avoid this error ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What are you tryin to do? It will return the value that was selected when the form was submitted.

Comment: I want to obtain a list of selected element in a List<String>.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
def mymethod() {
    List<String> portalsChoice = params.portalsChoice
}
```

with

```
def mymethod() {
    List<String> portalsChoice = params.list('portalsChoice')
}
```

The `portalsChoice` list will contain the selected elements, regardless of how many were selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a check in your controller:

```
List<String> portalsChoice = []
if(params.portalsChoice instanceof String){
   //force it to be a list 
   portalsChoice = params.list('portalsChoice')
}else{
//for multiple 
  portalsChoice = params.portalsChoice 
}
```

not so tricky but helps resolve your issue.

Comment: I suspect the following would work in either case `List<String> portalsChoice = params.list('portalsChoice')`

Comment: Yes you are right instead of if and else block ,only one single line will do. List<String> portalsChoice = params.list('portalsChoice').The reason I gave this much code explanation as I pasted the tested code:).